# Testing entire airflow DAG not a single task

Tags: testing, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Folks, i spent 3-4 days googling to find some information to write python test cases to test an entire dag ( not tasks ).  Ii found nothing.
I wonder if it is even possible to do it, if so what are available options ?
Doesn't look like air flow provides anything easy to use.

Comment: I use the old way: I run the DAG from the UI and see what happens. Every DAG should be idempotent (no matter how many times you run it, the final output will be always the same), so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Testing a dag, end-to-end, isn't strictly necessary. Assume that the various functionality that Airflow provides is tested for you, so all you need to do is unit test whatever functionality you're providing. For example, if using a `PythonOperator`, just test the Python function in question with appropriate fixtures, mocks, etc

Comment: By test , do you mean to see if dags are executing in correct order ? You could use Airflow expiremental REST API to see , if task are starting and stopping in correct order

Comment: I'm surprised at the responses I see here. This should not be considered out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

```
airflow dags test dag_id_here 2021-11-10T14:20:00Z
```

The date needs to be in the past.

**NOTE:**
This specific timestamp **2021-11-10T14:20:00Z** represents **November 10, 2021, at 14:20:00 UTC**.

In the context of `airflow dags test` command, specifying a date in the past, such as **2021-11-10T14:20:00Z**, allows you to test the execution of the DAG as if it were executed at that particular point in time. This is useful for historical testing, backfilling tasks, or validating the behavior of the DAG under past conditions.

Comment: what does this date mean ?

Comment: This specific timestamp 2021-11-10T14:20:00Z represents November 10, 2021, at 14:20:00 UTC.

In the context of `airflow dags test` command, specifying a date in the past, such as 2021-11-10T14:20:00Z, allows you to test the execution of the DAG as if it were executed at that particular point in time. This is useful for historical testing, backfilling tasks, or validating the behavior of the DAG under past conditions.